# What is the difference between «референтный центр» и «референсный центр»?

Tags: значения, правописание, буквы

In English, the term "*reference center*" usually refers to a laboratory or a lab network created to pursue all the scientific and technical problems related to a specific narrow area, such as a specific disease, phenomenon, or class of chemicals.

In Russian, however, it appears that both «*референ**т**ный центр*» and «*референ**с**ный центр*» are used.
Is there a difference between the two, or are they used interchangeably?
If there *is* a difference, what does each term mean?

Comment: What's the difference between "reference center" and simply "center"? It's just that many narrow-area institutions in Russia are called just "центр того-то" with no mention of "reference" in any form. So I wonder what "reference" adds to the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when Russian borrows words from Latin, it uses the accusative form of Latin nouns and adjectives, and replaces the Latin endings with Russian ones. There are numerous exceptions to this rule, but for the most part, it works.

According to this rule, the "correct" form is *референтный*, which is indeed the only form that was in use before mid-80s.

That said, many Russian publications in the 90s and thereafter, just calqued or even borrowed English "reference center", which gave *референсный центр* and *референс-центр*, respectively.

I don't think there's a lot of difference between the two, but *референтный* is both older and more aligned with Russian scientific traditions.

Answer (score 3):

The best translation for "reference center" is справочный центр or справочно-информационный центр. While both референтный and референсный are so-called *loan translations* or calques, all the translations have the same meaning: "centers providing information to a specific narrow area of science".